# PHP MySQL Select Problem

Tags: php, sql, select

Why is my query not returning any results? I can run the query `SELECT * FROM`users`WHERE wid = 'worker_040'` and it returns a result just fine. Am I missing something in this?

```
$wid = $_POST['username'];
            $con = mysql_connect("11.88.3.2","XXXX","XXXXX");
            if (!$con)
                {
                    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                }

            mysql_select_db("chit", $con);

            echo "Form details<br />";

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE wid = '$wid'");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            echo $row['FirstName']. " - ". $row['LastName'];
            echo "<br />";
            }

        mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: It should be `$_POST['username']`.  Also, are you sure `$wid` has a value when you call the query?  What does the completed SQL actually look like right before you call `mysql_fetch_array()`?

Comment: @CharlesSprayberry Sorry I had that in my code, just didnt copy for some reason. Yes above this code just for testing I do `echo $wid` and it outputs something like worker_040

Comment: I know this is nit-picking but I would take your query out of the `$result` variable, put it in it's own `$query` variable then echo out the whole, complete SQL statement to ensure the entire thing matches against what works.  As long as the ID exists in your DB I don't see why this shouldn't be returning results.

Comment: After your query, print the output of `mysql_error`, and if there's no error in there, do a `var_dump($wid);` to check what is in there (do look at the _source_, not as an HTML page in a browser) (might be just a stray space that fouls things up for you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take some time to debug.

For example, make sure your script is accessed via an HTTP POST request and 'username' is sent in the request ($_POST['request'] is set and has a valid value which could/would return results).

Get some info after executing your queries (you could use mysql_error()), get the number of rows returned etc. Output your sql query before sending it for execution.

Print the value of each row in your while loop.

These are some hints/tips you could use for finding out what might be going on. There are also other ways but you could give the above a try.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your result rows as a numeric array but referencing them as an associative array - change your `while` loop to use `mysql_fetch_assoc`

**Edit - this probably isn't it!**

`mysql_fetch_array` returns the array as both an associative and numeric array by default, so shouldn't affect your code above.

Comment: thats what I thought at first too, but then I read up on the `mysql_fetch_array` and read the same thing. Thats why I am perplexed.